# Google API Translation

Tags: c++, c, google-api

https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de

In this URL, what is INSERT-YOUR-KEY? Any good tutorials on that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on using an API for a project, a highly recommended first step is to read the official documentation through fully:
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html

From the **introduction**:

> You need a Google account to use this API. If you already have a Google Account, then you can visit the Google APIs console to set up a new project and get your API key.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Google API key in order to use Google-provided APIs: http://code.google.com/apis/loader/signup.html

Comment: It needs to know a website in order to generate key, is that really neccessary?

Comment: @user2243, it is if you want to use Google APIs. :) They're curious who is using their services..

Comment: Can i just put a random website because i'm only gonna use it text translation.

Comment: One question, what do then mean by that `Signing up the URL http://www.mygooglesearchssite.com/mysite, for example, will create a key usable within all URLs in the http://www.mygooglesearchssite.com/mysite/ directory.`